# how to compile openssl with fvisibility=hidden flag for iOS

Tags: ios, gcc, compilation, openssl, compiler-flags

I need to compile the openssl code with -fvisibility=hidden to hide the large number of symbols and then use in Xcode.
Using below GitHub link.. I'm able get the libssl.a and libcrypto.a but there is no option I can see the build-libssl.sh (shell script) to add option "-fvisibility=hidden".

https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/blob/master/build-libssl.sh

I did try adding "-fvisibility=hidden" in "Other C Flags" in Build Settings in Xcode but does not seem to work. Hence please suggest for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the GitHub link mentioned, go to scripts folder -> build-loop-archs.sh
and then edit this file "build-loop-archs.sh" and replace the "-fembed-bitcode" with "-fvisibility=hidden" and then save it and run the script. It will work.

## Embed bitcode for SDK >= 9

```
 if [ "${CONFIG_DISABLE_BITCODE}" != "true" ]; then
    if [[ "${SDKVERSION}" == 9.* || "${SDKVERSION}" == [0-9][0-9].* ]]; then
      LOCAL_CONFIG_OPTIONS="${LOCAL_CONFIG_OPTIONS} -fvisibility=hidden"
    fi
  fi
```

https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/blob/master/build-libssl.sh